# Make extension cross-version compatible

Tags: vs-extensibility

I have a Visual Studio extension that does some intense initialization. To solve the issue I decided to extend my VSPackage from AsyncPackage.

All nice and well however now my extension is not compatible with VS 2010, 2012 and 2013.

Is there a way to solve this issue?

What I tried so far was to create 2 VS packages and use 2 manifests but that didn't really work out. Anyone else tried anything like this?

Answer (score 0):

AsyncPackage is only available for Visual Studio 2015.